# NMAP's explicitely closed ports

Tags: nmap, tcp, enumeration

I'm working on a challenge and I notice this odd output for a full port scan?

```
abc@desktop:~$ nmap -T5 -p- -sV x.x.x.x -PN

Interesting ports on x.x.x.x:
Not shown: 65533 filtered ports
PORT      STATE  SERVICE       VERSION
3389/tcp  open   microsoft-rdp Microsoft Terminal Service
11111/tcp closed unknown
Service Info: OS: Windows
```

I'm used to NMAP only displaying open ports. In this case the vast majority of ports were closed but NMAP explicitely stated port 60000 is closed.

What does an *explicitely* closed port mean?

Comment: Add `--reason` to get more information about why a port is in a particular state. For more on "filtered" see https://secwiki.org/w/FAQ_filtered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are performing a *SYN scan* or *TCP connect scan* (depending on your account permissions). With those scan types, you can receive the following port states based on the results of the [TCP handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment):

- **open:** An ACK packet was received, indicating that the connection was accepted.
- **closed:** A RST packet was received from the host or firewall, rejecting the connection.
- **filtered:** No response was received when attempting to connect to this port.

It is also worth noting that Nmap utilizes half-open scanning in the SYN scan mode because it never completes the TCP handshake. The idea is that this is more stealthy because logs often record when a connection is actually established.

Comment: Regarding the logs on a full three way handshake: This used to be the case, but this is no longer valid. Even if a three way handshake is not performed, it will show up in log files.

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox Do you have information about the prevalence of that behavior? I can confirm that a SYN scan is not passed on to a listening program on my Linux system whereas the connect scan is.

Comment: "Modern firewalls and Intrusion Detection Systems can detect SYN scans, but in combination with other features of Nmap, it is possible to create a virtually undetectable SYN scan by altering timing and other options." Source: https://nmap.org/bennieston-tutorial/ - So with just a SYN scan (-sS) You'll show up in logs. I am uncertain about iptables (assuming you're using that to test it), per your statement apparently it does not.

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox Thanks for the clarification. I was referring to the server software (Nginx, Apache, SSH, etc.). If additional protection/logging is being employed, then a SYN scan can (of course) be detected and logged.

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox That tutorial is way out of date, but that part is valid. I wrote more on the evasion/detection angle recently: http://blog.bonsaiviking.com/2015/07/they-see-me-scannin-they-hatin.html

Comment: Filtered can also be a result of certain ICMP responses like Destination Unreachable code 9, 10, or 13.

Comment: @bonsaiviking: Great article on your blog! Thanks for sharing.